# canDeactivate method of angular2 router, changing router state even if I select cancel from confirmation popUp

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am using canDeactivate method to block browser navigation in angular2. I am calling a confirmation popup, if user select cancel it doesn't move to another page but the state of the router is being changed. Using angular router version 4.4.4.

Comment: I have checked issue raised https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12851 and tried solutions provided there but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
export class DeactivateComponent implements CanDeactivate<MyComponent> {
    canDeactivate(component: MyComponent,
                  currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                  currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
                  nextState: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        return component.canDeactivate() || window.confirm("Proceed?");
    }
}
```

Typical path:

```
{path: ':id', component: MyComponent, canDeactivate: [DeactivateComponent]},
```